# CarbonEmacs, symbolic links and dired-find-file

Tags: symlink, carbon-emacs

When I list a directory (C-x-d), all symbolic links have names ending with '@'; eg.:

```
 .bashrc@ -> ./system/dot-bashr
```

Then when I try to open such a file with "e" or "f" (dired-find-file), I get the message:

```
    File no longer exists; type `g' to update dired buffer
```

Otherwise, all links work normally within Emacs.

Any hints?

-- Tsf

PS: I posted basically the same message before but I forgot the tags, and then did not see it appear. I appologize if it appears twice.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. For some historical reasons inherited from Unix and which I do not remember, my emacs profile.el had the line:

```
   (setq dired-listing-switches "-alF")
```

and these arguments are passed to the command "ls"; option  which marks symbolic links with '@'.

Sorry to bother everybody!

-- Tsf

Comment: Mac OS X *is* unix. Heck, if you have 10.5 or 10.6 it is Unix (TM).